# How to update image to a different thread?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I'm doing a simple project for a fingerprint image processing.

I'm trying to use threads on the part of the processing so that the UI kept in a smooth manner.

When I'm trying to display the fingerprint image while trying to process the histogram equalization, I got an error which said that the image is still used by another thread.

I've been trying to lookup on solutions like using `Freeze()` methods but I have no idea where to put it.

Here's my code.

```
private void btnLoadImage_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog openImg = new OpenFileDialog();
        openImg.FileName = "Fingerprint Image"; 
        openImg.DefaultExt = ".tif" ;
        openImg.Filter = "Image File (*.tif)|*.tif*|" +
            "JPEG Files (*.jpg, *.jpeg)|*.jpeg, *.jpeg|" + 
            "PNG Files (*.png)|*.png"; 

        Nullable<bool> result = openImg.ShowDialog();

        if (result == true)
        {
            imgDisp.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(openImg.FileName));
        }
    }

    private void btnGenKey_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (imgDisp.Source == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Upload Image First!");
        }
        else
        {
            imgDisp.Source.Freeze();
            BackgroundWorker doImg = new BackgroundWorker();
            doImg.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(doImg_DoWork);
            doImg.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(doImg_RunWorkerCompleted);
            doImg.RunWorkerAsync(imgDisp.Source);
        }
    }

    void doImg_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        ImageProcessor.BasicImgPro bip = new ImageProcessor.BasicImgPro();
        BitmapImage srcImg = (BitmapImage)imgDisp.Source;
        using (MemoryStream outImg = new MemoryStream())
        {
            BitmapEncoder enc = new BmpBitmapEncoder();
            enc.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(srcImg));
            enc.Save(outImg);
            Bitmap newBitmap = new Bitmap(outImg);
            Bitmap he = bip.HistoEqualize(newBitmap);
            using (var memory = new MemoryStream())
            {
                he.Save(memory, ImageFormat.Png);
                memory.Position = 0;

                var displayImg = new BitmapImage();
                displayImg.BeginInit();
                displayImg.StreamSource = memory;
                displayImg.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
                displayImg.EndInit();
                e.Result = displayImg;
            }
        }
    }

    void doImg_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Error.Message);
        }
        else
        {
            imgDisp.Source = (ImageSource)e.Result;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where exactly do you get the exception? Is it when you try to access the source image in your background worker, e.g. in line `enc.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(srcImg));`?

Comment: clemens: previously, the error showed up here : `BitmapImage srcImg = (BitmapImage)imgDisp.Source;` But when I try using invoke method, it caused the GUI to lag while processing the image.

thanks for the edit, Marcus Wigert. I was off for a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could clone the `BitmapImage` before passing it to the worker, but it would be altogether simpler to use a plain `Image` (i.e. `Bitmap`) for processing (since this is what image processing libraries use), and keep the `BitmapImage` for WPF display only:

```
private void btnLoadImage_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    using (var openImg = new OpenFileDialog())
    {
        ...

        if (openImg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Ok)
            LoadImage(openImg.FileName);
    }
}

private Bitmap _bitmap;
void LoadImage(string uri)
{
    // use a BitmapImage for display
    imgDisp.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(openImg.FileName));

    // use a Bitmap for processing
    _bitmap = new Bitmap(openImg.FileName);
}
```

This also means that you don't need to convert the `BitmapImage` to a `Bitmap` inside your `BackgroundWorker`:

```
// simply pass the bitmap instance to the worker
doImg.RunWorkerAsync(_bitmap);

// worker method gets simplified a bit
void doImg_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    var bip = new ImageProcessor.BasicImgPro();
    var bitmap = (Bitmap)e.Argument;
    var result = bip.HistoEqualize(bitmap);
    e.Result = result;
}

// convert to an image source when done
void doImg_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Error != null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Error.Message);
        return;
    }

    imgDisp.Source = ConvertBitmapToImageSource((Bitmap)e.Result);
}
```

Comment: is there any alternative for `ConvertBitmapToImageSource` ? I can't find it in .NET 4 Client Profile

Comment: @undip_student: no, sorry, I just presumed you would implement that in a separate method (it's what you were doing earlier inside `DoWork` using the `MemoryStream`, converting `he` to a new `BitmapImage`).